# Sections with rows and open subrows in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

Hi i have multiple sections.Each section contains number of rows and each row contains 2 to 5 sub rows.i need to these sub rows are open status. i want using here rows and sub rows using different custom cells.

Please share any idea or sample project.

Comment: What you exactly want? Not getting your question

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: you can implement this simply by checking the **indexpath.row** and the custom cell for each indexPath in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

Comment: People usually get better results on SO by writing their own code and asking for help on specific problems.  "*Write my program for me*" isn't usually received as well.

Comment: i want idea...not code

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing three links One is appcoda's tutorial to do this kind of stuff and other two are github project.

[Appcoda Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/)

[SLExpandableTableView](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView)

[KExpandTableView](https://github.com/jackkwok/JKExpandTableView)

Check it out. Hope this can help you. :)